# Cannot find declaration of the element company

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

my xml document company.xml,my xsd document companyxsd.xsd I don't know where I was getting wrong.Exception:cvc-elt:1.a:Cannot find declaration of element'company'.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <companies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd">
 <company>
 <companyname>capgemini</companyname>
 <address>chalapathischool</address>
 <department>
 <dname>cse</dname>
 <deptphoneno>995674314</deptphoneno>
 <deptfaxno>08776455508</deptfaxno>
 <deptemail>gvn@gmail.com</deptemail>
  <employee>
 <empid>1</empid>
 <ename>tarun</ename>
<emailid>tar@gmail.com</emailid>
<phoneno>1234567890</phoneno>
</employee>
<contractemployee>
<name>gvn</name>
 <phoneno>9989956882</phoneno>
 </contractemployee>
 </department>
 </company>
 </companies>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="companies">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="company" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="department" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="contractemployee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

I am confident that all my code was not wrong still i am getting error.If anyone who knows the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Listed below is a code for correct answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd">
<companyname>capgemini</companyname>
<address>chalapathischool</address>
<department>
<dname>cse</dname>
<deptphoneno>995674314</deptphoneno>
<deptfaxno>08776</deptfaxno>
<deptemail>gvn@gmail.com</deptemail>
<employee>
<empid>1</empid>
<ename>tarun</ename>
<emailid>tar@gmail.com</emailid>
<phoneno>1234567890</phoneno>
</employee>
<contractemployee>
<name>gvn</name>
<phoneno>9989956882</phoneno>
</contractemployee>
</department>
</company>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="company">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="department" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="contractemployee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```